# Cannot get updated coordinates to append them the array in SWIFT 4

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm trying to store into `actualRouteInUseAnnotation: [MKAnnotation]` start and end position for a route, and into `actualRouteInUseCoordinates : [CLLocationCoordinate2D]` all the coordinates for the route.
The annotation array gets it's values, but the coordinates array doesn't.

The functions used are:
For start:

```
func startTracking2() {

        self.trackingIsActive = true
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        let startRoutePosition = RouteAnnotation(title: "Route Start", coordinate: (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!, imageName: "Route Start")
        self.actualRouteInUseAnnotations.append(startRoutePosition)
//        self.actualRouteInUseCoordinates.append((locationManager.location?.coordinate)!)
        print(actualRouteInUseCoordinates)
        print(actualRouteInUseAnnotations)
    }
```

For stop:

```
func stopTracking2() {

        self.trackingIsActive = false
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        let stopRoutePosition = RouteAnnotation(title: "Route Stop", coordinate: (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!, imageName: "Route Stop")
        self.actualRouteInUseAnnotations.append(stopRoutePosition)
        print(actualRouteInUseCoordinates)
        print(actualRouteInUseAnnotations)

    }
```

and for updated coordinates:

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else { return }


//        setCoordinates() // set actual user coordinates
//        storeUserLocation() // store auctual user coordinates

        self.actualRouteInUseCoordinates.append(mostRecentLocation.coordinate)


    }
```

Can you see why I'm not appending aupdated coordinates to the array?

Comment: Shouldn't you call `startUpdatingLocation` in `startTracking2`?

Comment: @Paulw11. Sure, I couldn't see I was calling `stopUpdatingLocation()`instead. So sorry to waste your time with this silly mistakes. Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Sometimes all it takes is a second pair of eyes